# Styling JSON Schema Form using classNames and styled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

Very new to this whole react thing, but from what I understand, the `schema` determines what the form data should be:

```
var schema = {
    type: "array",
    title: "Season Data",
    items: {
        type: "object",
        required: ["name", "shortname"],
        properties: {
            name: {
                type: "string",
                maxLength: 30
            },
            shortname: {
                type: "string",
                maxLength: 6,
                pattern: "^s\\d*$" //must start with s and end with number
            },
            starts_at: {
                type: "string"
            },
            ends_at: {
                type: "string"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

While the `uiSchema` determines what it should look like:

```
let uiSchema = {
    name: {
        classNames: "bold-title",
        "ui:placeholder" : "Season name"
    },
    shortname: {
        "ui:placeholder" : "Assign a shortname (e.g. s5)"
    },
    starts_at: {
        classNames: "label-date-align",
        "ui:widget": dateWidget,
    },
    ends_at: {
        classNames: "label-date-align",
        "ui:widget": dateWidget
    }
}
```

Both of those are in a `page_schema.js`, along with this:

```
const dateWidget = props => {
    return (
        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <KeyboardDateTimePicker
                format="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"
                value={props.value}
                onChange={(date, value) => {
                    let jsonDate = date && date.toJSON();
                    props.onChange(jsonDate || value);
                }}
                inputVariant="outlined"
            />
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    );
};
```

Here's the `page_form.js`:

```
class SeasonForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={ seasonsData: [], seasonsDataIndex: 0, formData: {} };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Box>
                <SchemaForm
                    liveValidate
                    schema={seasonSchema}
                    uiSchema={seasonUiSchema}
                    widgets={customWidgets}
                    >
                </SchemaForm>
            </Box>
        );
    }
}

export default styled(SeasonForm) ({
    "& .label-date-align" : {
        verticalAlign: "middle",
        lineHeight: "50px",
    },
    "& .reward-list label" : {
        display: "none"
    },
});
```

But for some reason the exported style just wouldn't take effect. Inspecting the code in Chrome reveals that the className `label-date-align` is being assigned properly, but it looks terrible, and even a simple text color change wouldn't work.

[image]

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: What's your .css or .scss file looks like? Do you have all the fonts installed? react-jsonschema-form is using also *glyphicon*  and other fonts-families.

Comment: Missing code for MuiPickersUtilsProvider, DateFnsUtils, and KeyboardDateTimePicker